# the_date(); is not displaying after additional posts

Tags: php, wordpress

Currently having a little bit of an issue in Wordpress with displaying the date after loading recent posts.

On the most recent post, the post is displayed with the date. Previous posts do not display the date.

I am using the_time() to get the time the post was created, and that is working just fine for all of my consecutive posts.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="sectionContainer col-xs-10">

<div class="sectionHeader">
    <p>Recent posts <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/gator-alt.svg" class="img-responsive pull-right"></p>
</div>

<div class="postContainer">

    <?php query_posts('showposts=5');

        if( have_posts() ): while( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>

        <p class="postTitle">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
        </p>

        <p class="postDateTime">
            <?php the_date();?> @
                <?php the_time();?>
        </p>

        <div class="postContentContainer">
            <p class="postContents">
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </p>
        </div>

        <?php endwhile;
              endif;

        ?>
</div>
```

And here is an image that fully depicts what is happening. You can see the most recent post displays the date, the previous posts do not.

[image: the_date(); display issue]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the following from [the_date()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_date/) function.

*Will only output the date if the current post’s date is different from the previous one output.*

Try using the function [get_the_date()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_date/)

Comment: Absolutely. Thanks for your help. This is my first Wordpress theme, so I'm positive I've asked a pretty basic question haha.